# How do I disable custom css on frontend with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, css

I currently have a custom CSS file specified in Settings > Resource URLS. In this CSS file I override some civicrm.css styles to make the CiviCRM admin screens look a little more like the Wordpress admin area. However, I would like to disable this file when viewing frontend pages e.g. contribution pages.

I've tried the basic usage of the Wordpress wp_dequeue_script option but I can't find what the handle is for this file, so this doesn't work.

Note: I have successfully disabled the standard civicrm.css on my front end pages with this code in functions.php suggested by another user:

```
function rs_remove_civicrm_styles() {

  global $civicrm_root;

  if (empty($civicrm_root)) {
   return; 
  }

  $civicrm_css = CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->getUrl('civicrm', 'css/civicrm.css', TRUE);
  CRM_Core_Region::instance('html-header')->update($civicrm_css, array('disabled' => TRUE));

}
```

But I'm not sure same method can be used for the custom css file?

Answer (score 2):

It might be simpler to just tweak the css to apply only to the admin pages using body.wp-admin (there may be more specific CiviCRM or WP classes you can use).

Comment: Thanks. I've already done that now, but it being a large project I'm keen to cut down on the nmber of resources files loaded, and as I'm copying most of the civi front end pages I need and styling them from my main wp stylesheet I really would like to prevent my custom css from being loaded

Comment: Ah, I get you. I'm not on a computer at the moment, so can't try this out, but I think the handle for de-enqueuing the custom css is just civicrm_custom_css

Comment: I've tried again with various combinations of both wp_dequeue_style and wp_dequeue_script but nothing seems to work. My custom css is located at /wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom/css/custom.css, but I'm not sure what exact dequeue should be i.e. by a handle(?) or path to that file, or even if dequue works at all. If you have 5 mins to test this sometime and post code I would be grateful.

Comment: Hm - I'm not having any joy with either dequeueing or trying to find the equivalent method for disabling it as you've disabled the default stylesheet... I will have a further look at how CiviCRM is hooked into wp_head :/

Comment: How do you feel about disabling all the css in CiviCRM and running the CiviCRM css through your WP theme (or a WP plugin)?

Comment: That's a possible workaround i.e. enqueuing my own custom css for civi just in admin area. I'll give that a try, although this non urgen now in that I've amended my wordpress.tpl to class="crm-container{if $urlIsPublic} crm-public{else} crm-admin{/if}" i.e. defining unique top level id via which to separate css.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, the block of code to drop into your functions.php to disable civiCRM CSS on the front-end only looks like this:

```
// Remove the CiviCRM styles from front-end displays.
function my_remove_civicrm_styles() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        global $civicrm_root;
        if (empty($civicrm_root)) {
            return;
        }
        $civicrm_css = CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->getUrl('civicrm', 'css/civicrm.css', TRUE); CRM_Core_Region::instance('html-header')->update($civicrm_css, array('disabled' => TRUE));
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_remove_civicrm_styles', 100 );
```

Answer (score 1):

[CiviCRM Admin Utilities](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civicrm-admin-utilities/) version 0.4.1 introduces options on the plugin's Settings screen to disable (on the front-end of your website):

- the default CiviCRM stylesheet
- the CiviCRM menu stylesheet

And, when the Shoreditch extension is enabled, you can also disable:

- the Shoreditch custom stylesheet
- the Shoreditch Bootstrap stylesheet

For reference, the following code will disable *any* custom stylesheet defined in CiviCRM when not in WordPress admin:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_disable_resources', 9 );
function my_disable_resources() {

    // front-end only please
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    // bail if CiviCRM isn't present and inited
    if ( ! function_exists( 'civi_wp' ) ) return;
    if ( ! civi_wp()->initialize() ) return;

    // get CiviCRM config
    $config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();

    // bail if there's no custom CSS file
    if ( empty( $config->customCSSURL ) ) return;

    // get registered URL
    $url = CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addCacheCode( $config->customCSSURL );

    // get registration data from region
    $registration = CRM_Core_Region::instance('html-header')->get( $url );

    // bail if not registered
    if ( empty ( $registration ) ) return;

    // set to disabled
    CRM_Core_Region::instance('html-header')->update( $url, array( 'disabled' => TRUE ) );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an improvement for @[jeff-van-loben-sels](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/2708/jeff-van-loben-sels)'s answer (which saved my day). I've just added a condition on `CRM_Core_Resources` to prevent a fatal error.

```
function my_remove_civi_style() {
  if (!is_admin()) {
    global $civicrm_root;
    if (!class_exists('CRM_Core_Resources') || empty($civicrm_root)){
        return;
    }
    $civicrm_css = CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->getUrl('civicrm', 'css/civicrm.css', TRUE); CRM_Core_Region::instance('html-header')->update($civicrm_css, array('disabled' => TRUE));
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_remove_civi_style', 100 );
```